# com.roughike.swipeselector.SwipeSelector not inflating

Tags: android, layout, layout-inflater

I downloaded the swipeselector from the android arsenal but I receive this error:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.roughike.swipeselector.SwipeSelector

my project is using the sdkversion 23 and I used the information described in the sample. Has anyone else had this problem?

Here is the stacktrace dump:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ida.android.getmeout2/com.ida.android.getmeout2.SettingsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.roughike.swipeselector.SwipeSelector
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.roughike.swipeselector.SwipeSelector
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172)
                                                                           at com.ida.android.getmeout2.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:65)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.roughike.swipeselector.SwipeSelector
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172) 
                                                                           at com.ida.android.getmeout2.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:65) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172) 
                                                                           at com.ida.android.getmeout2.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:65) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                           at com.roughike.swipeselector.SwipeSelector.init(SwipeSelector.java:106)
                                                                           at com.roughike.swipeselector.SwipeSelector.<init>(SwipeSelector.java:49)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172) 
                                                                           at com.ida.android.getmeout2.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:65) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                           at com.roughike.swipeselector.SwipeSelector.init(SwipeSelector.java:106) 
                                                                           at com.roughike.swipeselector.SwipeSelector.<init>(SwipeSelector.java:49) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172) 
                                                                           at com.ida.android.getmeout2.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:65) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                           at com.roughike.swipeselector.SwipeSelector.init(SwipeSelector.java:106) 
                                                                           at com.roughike.swipeselector.SwipeSelector.<init>(SwipeSelector.java:49) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172) 
                                                                           at com.ida.android.getmeout2.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:65) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attr
```

Comment: please add layout code and crash log

Comment: Did you add it through Gradle or how did you add it to your project?

Comment: I added it through gradle. I followed the directions from the android arsenal page.